# upgrade ruby on rails on mac sierra error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, homebrew

I'm having problems to update my ruby and install rails, everything seems to be installed

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
Warning: rbenv-1.1.0 already installed
Warning: ruby-build-20170405 already installed
thiagos-Air:~ thiagobaptistella$ rbenv install 2.4.1
rbenv: /Users/thiagobaptistella/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N) n
thiagos-Air:~ thiagobaptistella$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

system MacOS Sierra version 10.12.4 (16E195)

For that reason can't instal rails.

any thoughts ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the required ruby version before using  it. You can set it locally as `rbenv local 2.4.1` or globally as `rbenv global 2.4.1`.

Comment: Yup, that should do it. Little side note, using `rbenv global` sets the version here `~/.rbenv/version`.